# segmentation fault when installing librsvg2-common and libgdk-pixbuf2.0

Tags: dpkg, software-installation

**If you are also affected, upvote the question so it causes more attention.**

My system is ubuntu 12.04 on Linux 3.8.0-37-generic. I got some crash report after a system update today (seemly from `librsvg2-common`). After I reboot the PC, I notice some of the icons are missing. In addition, I cannot open some image files formats like .png files. After some googling I tried to re-install `librsvg`-related packages. But I constantly got Segmentation fault

```
Unpacking librsvg2-common (from .../librsvg2-common_2.36.1-0ubuntu1.1_amd64.deb) ... 
Processing triggers for libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0 ... 
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
Setting up librsvg2-common (2.36.1-0ubuntu1.1) ... 
Processing triggers for libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0 ... 
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

I also tried to force reinstall libgdk-pixbuf2.0 related package but got segmentation fault, too.

I also tried:

```
sudo rm /var/cache/apt/*.bin
```

and

```
sudo apt-get install -f
```

but it did not help. I downloaded the .deb package and tried installing it but same segfault msg.

How could I possibly have `libgdk-pixbuf2.0` and `librsvg2-common` packages installed? Or can I roll back to the point before the system update?

**Update**:
I carefully checked all the dependencies' versions in the [precise-update](http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise-updates/libs/) database and none of them have problems.

Comment: see my other question for the consequence of this segfaults issue:
http://askubuntu.com/questions/436791/eog-does-not-recognize-png-file-format-and-many-icons-are-gone

Comment: after editing /var/lib/dpkg/triggers/File, the force re-installation of libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0 still gives segfault (core dump) :-(

Comment: But after the unsuccessful force re-installation, I notice four new lines added to the `/var/lib/dpkg/triggers/File`: `/usr/lib/gdk-pixbuf-2.0/2.10.0/loaders libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gdk-pixbuf-2.0/2.10.0/loaders libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0
/usr/lib/gdk-pixbuf-2.0/2.10.0/loaders libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0:i386
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/gdk-pixbuf-2.0/2.10.0/loaders libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0:i386`. **Three** folds are mentioned. But I do **not** have the fold `/usr/lib/gdk-pixbuf-2.0` on my system. I have only the other two.

Comment: @Sneetsher, I do not get it. What is this new suggestion different from the previous?

Comment: @Sneetsher, this is a segfault issue. I doubt such fiddling would fix it.

Comment: Unable to comment...
Launchpad bug: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gdk-pixbuf/+bug/1174253 Please add your info to the bug

Comment: Same issue here since automatic update yesterday. I was on unity and I think this bug prevented compiz form launching at all, had to switch to xfce to be able to use my laptop. The launchpad bug is one year old.. Any chance this gets resolved..?

Comment: What program is segfaulting? Since you're getting a core file, find it, and do:
    `file core`

Comment: @mlv: I could not find the core file in either local dir or `/var/crash` after following [instruction for apport](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Apport) as well as [suggestions from stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6152232/how-to-generate-core-dump-file-in-ubuntu). Only empty files with suffix `.upload` are found in `/var/crash`

Comment: `find / -name core -ls` It should be somewhere. Maybe in /var/lib/dpkg?

Comment: obviously, it is not dumped as I could not find a single core file using `sudo find / -name core -ls`. What I have done includes : `ulimit -c unlimited`, `sudo nano /etc/apport/crashdb.conf` and comment out the line as suggested in ubuntu wiki. Then I force install `libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0` and got  segfault. And no core was even found.